# Movable Type: MTIf not working under MTSubCategories?

Tags: movabletype

I'm trying to insert UL on every 20th sub category label.
This code below doesn't seem to work. It only exports list of sub categories without the UL in it's right place.

Any one know what would be wrong?

```
<MTTopLevelCategories>
<ul>
<MTSubCategories>
<mt:If name="__counter__" op="%" value="20" eq="1">
<mt:If name="__counter__" ne="1">
</ul>
<ul></mt:If></mt:If>
<li><$MTCategoryLabel$></li>
</MTSubCategories>
</ul>
</MTTopLevelCategories>
```

My testing environment:
Movable Type 5.01
PHP 5.2.11
MySQL 5
Perl 5.8.9

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I recall and according to the "[Proposal:Iterator template tag consistency](http://wiki.movabletype.org/Proposal:Iterator_template_tag_consistency)" wiki page, the `__counter__` meta variable is not available under `<mt:SubCategories>`. Unfortunately, MT lacks consistent use of the meta variables, but you can create your own counter variable to do the same thing.

```
<MTTopLevelCategories>
  <$mt:SetVar name="subcatcount" value="1"$>
  <ul>
    <MTSubCategories>
      <mt:If name="subcatcount" op="%" value="20" eq="1">
        <mt:If name="subcatcount" ne="1">
          </ul>
          <ul>
        </mt:If>
      </mt:If>
      <li><$MTCategoryLabel$></li>
      <$mt:SetVar name="subcatcount" value="1" op="add"$>
    </MTSubCategories>
  </ul>
</MTTopLevelCategories>
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked!

Maybe I will send feed back to SA about adding this variable to this tag.